# exponential map of SU(4)

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

Good day,

From my reading, I understand that there are 15 parameters needed to produce an arbitrary element of the SU(4) Lie group. This is because this group contains 15 generators.

My question is: if I select one or two parameters to produce one such element in SU(4), and then multiply it with its transpose, why don't I get the identity matrix?.

Here the example.

Given SU(4) paramterization:

$$U=e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_1}e^{i\lambda_2\alpha_2}e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_3}e^{i\lambda_5\alpha_4}e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_5}e^{i\lambda_{10}\alpha_6}e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_7}e^{i\lambda_2\alpha_8}e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_9}e^{i\lambda_5\alpha_{10}}e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_{11}}e^{i\lambda_2\alpha_{12}}e^{i\lambda_3\alpha_{13}}e^{i\lambda_8\alpha_{14}}e^{i\lambda_{15}\alpha_{15}}$$

My problem is: I want to manipulate the value of parameter $\alpha_2$ with the rest parameter constant by substitute the parameter with 00(make them Identity matrix). Hence, I expand the Exponential with generator $\lambda_2$ given as below,

$$\lambda_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0& -i &
0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}$$

and I get the expansion :

$$cos\alpha_2\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} + i sin\alpha_2\begin{pmatrix} 0& -i &
0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}$$

and get the matrix of $e^{i\lambda_2\alpha_2}$

$$\begin{pmatrix} cos\alpha_2& sin\alpha_2 &
0 & 0 \\ -sin\alpha_2 & cos\alpha_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}$$

When I make $UU^{\dagger}$, it suppose to get identity matrix. But I cant get it. Why? please help me where the mistake I expansion.

I use this expansion:
$$e^{i\alpha_2\lambda_2}=1+i\alpha_2\lambda_2+\frac{(i\alpha_2\lambda_2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(i\alpha_2\lambda_2)^3}{3!}. . . $$
$$=(1-\frac{(i\alpha_2)^2}{2!}+...)\lambda^2_2 + i (\alpha_2-\frac{(i\alpha_2)^3}{3!}+..)\lambda_2$$
$$= cos\alpha_2\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} + i sin\alpha_2\begin{pmatrix} 0& -i &
0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &
0 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}$$

why the two end row not equal to 1. Please correct me the expansion.
I'm really stuck here.

Thank you very much

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\hskip 1in$ [image: pic]

You replaced $1$ (blue) with $1\cdot\lambda_2^2$ (green). That's why you're missing a $2\times 2$ identity matrix in the lower right block. You also have incorrect signs in the second line (first is in red). Since you left the powers of $i$ uncomputed you shouldn't have any minus signs yet.

Comment: Thank you. hence, with value must I replaced it? I really confuse

Comment: @munirah Split the identity matrix up into the upper left block and lower right block. The former will be absorbed into the power series.

Comment: $\lambda^2_2 $ is the matrix beside $cos \alpha_2$. please help me

Comment: @munirah What do you want help with?

Comment: I just get your respond. How I split the matrix up into the left block and lower right block? i dont understand.

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}}_{\large \lambda_2^2} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: thank you @artic. you are so kind.  so, the 1st matrix,can be used in \

Comment: In this case, the identity matrix must be split out into two part to get the form of the $\lambda^2_2$ ? May I right?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Comment: may I know, why this is be like this? can you give  a link/book to me understand this

Comment: @munirah The exponential function is defined by a power series that includes the identity matrix and powers. If you take a block diagonal matrix with one of the blocks zeroed out, all of its powers will have the same shape, which contrasts with the identity matrix. This is a simple concept, there's not going to be a whole book about this. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: oooo..now, I understand it. Thank you very much you help and explaintion, really appreciate it.

Comment: Already solve my problem by @arctic. Thank you very much